# How do I access an ArrayList (that was implemented in a superclass) in a subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, subclass, superclass

I have the following problem:
I have four classes (Student, Subject, HighSchool, Scientific)
the class HighSchool extends Student and the class Scientific extends HighSchool.

in the class HighSchool I made an ArrayList of objects of type Subject (and named it "subjects") and I made a method to calculate the average using that ArrayList.

Now, I want to override that method in the class Scientific (it was used in the parent class and I want to use it in the child class), but for that I need to use the arraylist of subjects and I don't know how to access it in the Scientific class.
I tried doing this:

in the super class, the method looks like this and it works perfectly fine

```
public double calculateAverage() {
        if (this.subjects.size()<=0) 
            return 0;
        double sum=0;
        for(int i=0; i<this.subjects.size(); i++) {
            sum+=this.subjects.get(i).getMark();
        }
        return (sum/this.subjects.size());
```

Here I tried to override it but it didn't work (the arraylist stays empty, the subjects are not being added to the arraylist). It's much complicated than that but I tried to simplify it

```
public double calculateAverage() {
        if (this.getSubjects().size() <= 0) 
            return 0;
        
        double sum = 0;
else{
for (int i = 0; i < getSubjects().size(); i++) {


sum += this.getSubjects().get(i).getMark();
                
            }
```

obviously, me using `this.getSubjects()` is not correct but I don't know what else I could use

NOTE: I'm not very experienced with this website so I'm sorry if my question isn't formatted well!

Edit: I tried using the `super` keyword and tried changing modifiers but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Please [edit} the post and format the code properly. --- "*obviously, me using `this.getSubjects()` is not correct ...*" - Why? Please [edit] the post and provide a precise problem description, as well as a [MRE].

Comment: There's the `protected` access modifier which makes an element visible to itself and subclasses. The fact you stated "I tried to override but the list was empty" tells me you might have a duplicate `List<Subject>` in your subclass, and you're not referencing the superclass's list via `super.subjects` (or `super.getSubjects()`, or even `this.getSubjects()` if you did not override it).

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers